# Split string without delimiter in PHP

Tags: php

For example, I have a string **"MThF"**. This stands for Monday **(M)**, Thursday **(Th)** and Friday **(F)**. I want to be able to split this string in PHP, but unfortunately, the string won't come with any delimiters. How do I solve this problem? I tried doing preg_replace but to no avail.

Here is a sample code I tried:

```
$keywords = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])/", "//", "MThF");
print_r($keywords);
```

This should work with all days of the week btw. **M** is Monday, **T** is Tuesday, **W** Wednesday, **Th** Thursday, **F** Friday, **Sat** is Saturday and **Sun** is Sunday.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How would `preg_replace` perform a split? And why are you replacing all the matches with `//`?

Comment: hey the one that you linked is the solution to my problem. thanks!